# Полный список стандартов С/С++

Tags: c++, c, стандарт

Какие диалекты и стандарты С и С++ существуют/существовали? Интересует **полный** список как для С, так и для С++, а также возможные их эквивалентные имена. Желательно в хронологическом порядке их публикации.

Comment: и что же людям в поисковиках то не ищется... Забанили что ли?!

Comment: @ArchDemon: Stack Overflow это место куда поисковики направляют (а чтобы найти ответ на Stack Overflow, сперва кто-то должен задать вопрос). Другое дело, что не ясно что такое "полный" список и что такое диалект, стандарт, например нужно ли включить [CINT (используется ROOT)](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint)?

Comment: @ArchDemon: не нашел до первого ответа здесь и похожего на него.

Comment: @jfs: да, предполагается, было бы неплохо оформить отдельным ответом или категорией в существующем ответе, например "диалекты", "специализированные", ... Понятно, что идеально полного видимо не выйдет получить.

Comment: А различные извращения типа [C--](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/tbone/c--/) считаются?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно так:

**C**:

- K&R C
- C89 | ANSI C | ANSI X3.159-1989
- C99 | ISO/IEC 9899:1999
- C11 | ISO/IEC 9899:2011

**C++**:

- C++98 | ISO/IEC 14882:1998
- C++03 | ISO/IEC 14882:2003
- C++07/TR1 | ISO/IEC TR 19768:2007
- C++11 | ISO/IEC 14882:2011
- C++14 | ISO/IEC 14882:2014
- C++17

Еще в компиляторах бывают свои слабодокументированные расширения или, наоборот, неполная поддержка стандарта, специфичные для компилятора директивы препроцессора, а также встречаются языки содержащие С как подмножество со своими стандартами и еще много всего. Так что ответ в общем-то практически бесполезен.

Чтобы глубже понять ситуацию, я бы на вашем месте посмотрел на язык `Forth`, в нем вообще из-за особенностей грамматики каждый пользователь создает свою собственную реализацию для решения нужной ему задачи.

Comment: Человеку нужен **полный** список диалектов. Требую включить в список мой курсовик по "теории языков программирования" :)

Comment: Тем более, что всё это есть в Википедии, в т.ч. категории C++ programming language family и C programming language family.

Comment: А если серьезно, то каждый уважающий себя компилятор обязательно умеет обрабатывать какой-нибудь свой неповторимый диалект. За примером далеко ходить не надо: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html (gnu89, gnu90, gnu99 и т.д.).

Comment: @VisioN: Там внизу есть поле "Ваш ответ". Сделайте выжимку курсовой, будет наверняка интересно.

Comment: @VladD Нет уж. Во первых, мой ответ вряд ли будет соответствовать условиям вопроса: тут же не просят написать новый диалект для Си. А во вторых, эту курсовую еще где-то откопать нужно.. уж больше 10 лет прошло. Но факт остается фактом: курсач был засчитан, следовательно на один диалект Си в мире точно больше :)