# Как скопировать значения из std::map в std::vector с помощью std::copy

Tags: c++, словари, контейнеры

Цель – в одну строку скопировать все *значения* из `std::map` в `std::vector`.

Да, вместо использования `std::copy` можно просто в цикле перебрать все значения словаря и закинуть их в вектор. Тем не менее, интересует именно реализация с помощью `std::copy`.

Минимальный пример:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    m[0] = "Hello";
    m[7] = "Heey";
    m[-59] = "R";
    m[1024] = "Rrrrrrrrroooooooooocccccccckkkkkk";

    std::vector<std::string> res;
    
    //  Хочется, чтобы строка работала как-то так, но проблема в том, что элементы словаря – пары, а не только значения
    // std::copy(m.begin(), m.end(), res.begin());

    // Здесь планирую получить вывод в виде всех значений словаря m
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator elem = res.begin(); elem != res.end(); ++elem)
        std::cout << *elem << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Таким образом, с моей точки зрения, вопрос сводится к следующему: как получить итератор на последовательность **значений** словаря, не беря во внимание ключи? То есть, чтобы, разыменовав итератор, получать не `std::pair`, а `std::string` в моём случае.

P.S. Использую **C++07**, то есть, мне **не доступен** функционал, появившийся в **C++11** (Просьба не спрашивать, почему. Так нужно и нужно не мне.)

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, поправил. Основывался на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415383/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%A1-%D0%A1

Comment: */минутка занудства/* `с++/tr1` не является ни самостоятельной версией языка ни стандартом оного, как таковым... а также название «**c++07**» ни где не фигурирует и не является общеупотребительным... это скорее предложение с расширениями стандартной библиотеки, которые позже войдут в с++11...

Comment: Тоже не понял, что такое C++07. Для стандартов же есть канонический вопрос-ответ здесь [Где взять стандарт С++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417797/Где-взять-стандарт-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В С++ итератора, для значений словаря из коробки нет до сих пор (ещё не смотрел, поправят ли что-то в C++20). Печально, но факт. Зато своя обёртка для этого делается на коленке довольно просто. В элементарном случае это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
template <typename T>
class second_unwrap_iterator : public T {
public:
  second_unwrap_iterator(T base)
    : T(base)
  { }

  const typename T::value_type::second_type& operator*() {
    return T::operator*().second;
  }
};

template <typename T>
second_unwrap_iterator<T> second_unwraper(T base) {
  return second_unwrap_iterator<T>(base);
}

// ...

std::copy(second_unwraper(m.cbegin()), second_unwraper(m.cend()),
          std::back_inserter(res));
```

`second_unwraper()` необходим только для того чтобы не указывать параметры шаблона в конструкторе. Начиная с С++17 вывод типов в шаблонах [улучшили](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) и можно обойтись без оного:

```
std::copy(second_unwrap_iterator(m.begin()), second_unwrap_iterator(m.end()), 
          std::back_inserter(res));
```

Comment: Не думаю, что  итератора, для значений словаря из коробки будут иметь  обширное использование =>  такого рода поправок не ожидаю ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я скорее ожидаю, что *boost*'овский `transform_iterator` добавят...

Comment: не спорю, но мне так кажется. А что вы думаете по поводу итератора, умеющий проходить по коллекции с заданными срезами?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ты имеешь в виду итерировать по срезам массива заданной длины? если честно, как-то не задумывался об этом... в состоянии «на сейчас» не особо понятно, что `operator*` должен возвращать... пару итераторов? а в состоянии «скоро», т.к. вроде как *Range*'и и `boost::adaptors` перетаскивают в стандарт (но я пока не разбирался, что там грядёт), то в принципе можно сделать такой адаптер...

Comment: Да, к примеру я часто выполняю экономические расчеты, а там матрицы часто используются, и у меня класс матрицы использует итератор, у которого есть методы `void set_mode(const std::gslice& ) noexcept` и `void set_mode(const std::slice& )  noexcept`,  после вызова которых итератор  ходит по заданным срезам. Очень удобно (могу итерировать практически как хочу), даже при наличии всех  соответствующих методов матричного класса.

Comment: Ещё `typename` перед `T::value_type` с 20 необязательно писать

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению `std::copy` для этой цели не годится. Рекомендую воспользоваться алгоритмом `std::for_each` или `std::transform`. Для старого стандарта придется написать функтор, а для С++11 и выше достаточно будет лямбды:

1. Пример решения с for_each:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <map>
   #include <algorithm>

   //Функтор для вставки в вектор (в С++11 в нем нет необходимости)
   class BackInserter
   {
   public:
       explicit BackInserter(std::vector<std::string>& vec) :
           m_ref_vec(vec)
        {}

       void operator()(const std::pair<int, std::string>& element)
       {
           m_ref_vec.push_back(element.second);
       }

   private:
       std::vector<std::string>& m_ref_vec;
   };

   int main()
   {
       std::map<int, std::string> m;
       m[0] = "Hello";
       m[7] = "Heey";
       m[-59] = "R";
       m[1024] = "Rrrrrrrrroooooooooocccccccckkkkkk";

       std::vector<std::string> res;
       BackInserter fInserter(res);

       std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), fInserter);

       // C++11 
       //std::for_each(
       //   m.begin(), 
       //   m.end(), 
       //   [&res](const std::pair<int, std::string>& element)
       //{
       //   res.push_back(element.second);
       //});

       // Здесь планирую получить вывод в виде всех значений словаря m
       for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator elem = res.begin(); elem != res.end(); ++elem)
           std::cout << *elem << std::endl;

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Пример решения с transform:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <map>
   #include <algorithm>

   class TransformFunctor
   {
   public:
       std::string operator()(const std::pair<int, std::string>& element)
       {
           return element.second;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       std::map<int, std::string> m;
       m[0] = "Hello";
       m[7] = "Heey";
       m[-59] = "R";
       m[1024] = "Rrrrrrrrroooooooooocccccccckkkkkk";

       std::vector<std::string> res;
       res.resize(m.size());
       std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), res.begin(), TransformFunctor());

       //C++11
       //std::transform(
       //    m.begin(), 
       //    m.end(),
       //    res.begin(),
       //    [](const std::pair<int, std::string>& element)->std::string
       //{
       //    return element.second;
       //});


       // Здесь планирую получить вывод в виде всех значений словаря m
       for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator elem = res.begin(); elem != res.end(); ++elem)
           std::cout << *elem << std::endl;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: А почему не `transform`?

Comment: можно и `std::transform`, это дело вкуса. Если есть необходимость, могу дополнить ответ.

Comment: я скорее не из фкуса, а из того, что: 1) `for_each` морально устарел после появления `range based` циклов; 2) с `transform` код будет меньше и лаконичнее (если, конечно, вопрошающий знаком с лямбдами)

Comment: range base как и лямбды появились в C++11, поэтому для решения с функторами большой разницы нет. Добавил в ответ реализацию с `transform`

Comment: Отформатируйте первый пример (там лишний пробел перед каждой строчкой)